# FFmpeg: concat multiple videos, some with audio, some without

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to concatenate 5 videos where the first and last have no audio track. I have tried the following command:

```
    ffmpeg -i 1-copyright/copyright2018640x480.mp4 -i 2-openingtitle/EOTIntroFINAL640x480.mp4 -i 3-videos/yelling.mp4 -i 4-endtitle/EOTOutroFINAL640x480.mp4 -i 5-learnabout/Niambi640.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v:0] [0:a:0] [1:v:0] [1:a:0] [2:v:0] [2:a:0] [3:v:0] [3:a:0] [4:v:0] [4:a:0] concat=n=5:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output_video.mp4
```

and I get the output error:

```
    Stream specifier ':a:0' in filtergraph description [0:v:0] [0:a:0] [1:v:0] [1:a:0] [2:v:0] [2:a:0] [3:v:0] [3:a:0] [4:v:0] [4:a:0] concat=n=5:v=1:a=1 [v] [a] matches no streams.
```

I know the first and last videos have no audio but I dont know how to write the statement to ignore the audio track in those videos. I have tried removing the [0:a:0] but that just throws another error:

```
   Stream specifier ':v:0' in filtergraph description [0:v:0] [1:v:0] [1:a:0] [2:v:0] [2:a:0] [3:v:0] [3:a:0] [4:v:0] [4:a:0] concat=n=5:v=1:a=1 [v] [a] matches no streams.
```

It doesnt make sense and Im kinda lost.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you're concatenating audio as well, then all video inputs must be paired with an audio stream. If the file itself doesn't have any audio, then a dummy silent track can be used.

Use

```
ffmpeg -i 1-Video.mp4 -i 2-openingtitle/EOTIntroFINAL640x480.mp4
       -i 3-videos/yelling.mp4 -i 4-endtitle/EOTOutroFINAL640x480.mp4
       -i 5-learnabout/Niambi640.mp4 -f lavfi -t 0.1 -i anullsrc -filter_complex
       "[0:v:0][5:a][1:v:0][1:a:0][2:v:0][2:a:0][3:v:0][3:a:0][4:v:0][5:a] concat=n=5:v=1:a=1 [v][a]"
       -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output_video.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I now get this error
`code`
[Parsed_concat_0 @ 0x7f9fcd6114c0] Input link in2:v0 parameters (size 720x480, SAR 10:11) do not match the corresponding output link in0:v0 parameters (640x480, SAR 1:1)
[Parsed_concat_0 @ 0x7f9fcd6114c0] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_concat_0
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #4:0
`code`

Comment: ..and all the source files are 640 x 480

Comment: Yes, all videos must have the same resolution.Looks like the 3rd video is NTSC: 720x480. You can resize it by adding `scale=640:480,setsar=1,` before the concat filter.

Comment: I tried: ffmpeg -i 1-copyright/copyright2018640x480.mp4 -i 2-openingtitle/EOTIntroFINAL640x480.mp4 -i 3-videos/yelling.mp4 -i 4-endtitle/EOTOutroFINAL640x480.mp4 -i 5-learnabout/Niambi640.mp4 -f lavfi -t 0.1 -i anullsrc -filter_complex "[0:v:0][5:a][1:v:0][1:a:0][2:v:0][2:a:0][3:v:0][3:a:0][4:v:0][5:a] scale=640:480,setsar=1 concat=n=5:v=1:a=1 [v][a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output_video.mp4

OUTPUT:[AVFilterGraph @ 0x7fd564d12c80] Too many inputs specified for the "scale" filter.
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument

Comment: `"[2:v:0]scale=640:480,setsar=1[2v];[0:v:0][5:a][1:v:0][1:a:0][2v][2:a:0][3:v:0][3:a:0][4:v:‌​0][5:a]concat=n=5:v=1:a=1 [v][a]"`

Comment: Note: the value of `-t` (in this example is 0.1 of a second) have to be smaller or equal than the video file you want to make silence otherwise the duration of `-t` will be applied as the duration for the silenced video.

Comment: @Eftekhari - not worth mentionng - who's creating videos shorter than 0.1 sec?

Comment: @Gyan my point was how `-t` behaves in relation to the silencing media and it's good to know that.

Comment: @Eftekhari if i'm selecting 5 videos and 3rd video is mute then should i use `-f lavfi -t 0.1 -i anullsrc` after 3rd input and before 4th input?
and is the value of `t` will be same as the duration of that video's duration?

Comment: @Gyan does `[0:v:0][5:a]` and `[4:v:0][5:a]` means that first and last input don't have any audio file??

Comment: In the OP's case, yes.

Comment: @Gyan any one pls share working command which concat 3 mp4 video and audio is also synched and not lost.