# FFMPEG how to add dummy audio during video splicing

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to use FFMPEG to splice few videos and output one combined video.
I managed to get all video stream with this command :

```
ffmpeg.exe -i 1.mov -i 2.mov -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=1920:1080[v0];[1:v]scale=1920:1080[v1];[v0][v1] concat=n=2:v=1[v]" -map "[v]" out.mp4
```

Also, to add a dummy audio to a video with this command:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i 1.mov -f lavfi -i aevalsrc=0 -shortest -i out.mov
```

Above commands work perfectly, however 2.mov has an audio stream while 1.mov does not.

Is there any method that can set a dummy audio for 1.mov and then combine both video and audio streams from 1.mov and 2.mov at one go, so that output a combined video that can play sound when it is at clip 2.mov.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

`ffmpeg.exe -i 1.mov -i 2.mov -f lavfi -t 1 -i anullsrc -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=1920:1080[v0];[1:v]scale=1920:1080[v1];[v0][2:a][v1][1:a] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" out.mp4`

`-f lavfi -t 1 -i anullsrc` adds a silent 1 second audio input, which is used as a counterpart to the video input from 1.mov. The concat filter will pad the audio to match the video duration of 1.mov.

Comment: Hey Gyan, if I want to splice more than 2 files, and I am using following command:
 'ffmpeg.exe -i 1.mov -i 2.mp4 -i 4.mov -f lavfi -t 1 -i anullsrc -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=1920:1080[v0];[1:v]scale=1920:1080[v1];[2:v]scale=1920:1080[v2];[v0][3:a][v1][1:a][v2][3:a] concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -y out.mp4'
It is exactly the same as your command, but I add 4.mov at input index [2], and I take dummy audio index[3]. It failed to output a video, is there any error with my command?

Comment: Hey Gyan I have solved the issue by adding 'setsar=1', I saw this method from your answer for this post :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46057412/ffmpeg-concat-multiple-videos-some-with-audio-some-without
what does setsar do in the filter complex ?